# Azure B2C authentication screen does not show up

Tags: vb.net, webforms, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Asp.Net 4.7 WebForms legacy application written in vb.net. I need to add Azure B2C authentication. So I registred an app with Azure, and added OWIN middleware NuGet packages, and made all necessary configuration changes. I expect to see the log in screen when the application runs, and yet it does not happen. The application just runs without any authentication. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

Startup.vb:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin

<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(InfoWebCore.Startup))>
Namespace InfoWebCore
Public Class Startup
    Private Shared clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
    Private Shared aadInstance As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AadInstance")
    Private Shared tenant As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")
    Private Shared redirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RedirectUri")
    Public Shared SignInPolicyId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:SignInPolicyId")

    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId))
    End Sub

    Private Function AuthenticationFailed(ByVal notification As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        notification.HandleResponse()

        If notification.Exception.Message = "access_denied" Then
            notification.Response.Redirect("/")
        Else
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" & notification.Exception.Message)
        End If

        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Function CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ByVal policy As String) As OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        Dim options = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
            .AuthenticationType = policy,
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf AuthenticationFailed
            },
            .Scope = "openid",
            .ResponseType = "id_token",
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters With {
                .NameClaimType = "name"
            }
        }
        Return options
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="None" />

...

    <!-- Azure AD B2C Settings -->
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="laticreteb2c.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="8hq22y21-f12g-4a2d-b170-fdaa0b2dc467" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44379/signin-oidc" />
    <add key="ida:SignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signin" />
```

Execution does come to the Configuration() method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks good, please ensure your web.config is similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880

  -->
<configuration>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="c1874cf1-a4e5-4af1-bd43-b13f59dfbee3" />
    <add key="ida:MetadataAddress" value="https://alfredorevillaatmsftb.b2clogin.com/tfp/alfredorevillaatmsftb.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SI/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And your StartupAuth.vb is similar to:

```vb
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Extensions
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin

Partial Public Class Startup
    Private Shared clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
    Private Shared aadInstance As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AadInstance")
    Private Shared tenant As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")
    Private Shared redirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RedirectUri")
    Public Shared SignInPolicyId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:SignInPolicyId")

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId))

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ByVal policy As String) As OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        Dim options = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .MetadataAddress = "https://alfredorevillaatmsftb.b2clogin.com/tfp/alfredorevillaatmsftb.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SI/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .Scope = "openid",
            .ResponseType = "id_token"
        }
        Return options
    End Function

    Private Function AuthenticationFailed(ByVal notification As Notifications.AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
        notification.HandleResponse()

        If notification.Exception.Message = "access_denied" Then
            notification.Response.Redirect("/")
        Else
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" & notification.Exception.Message)
        End If

        Return Task.FromResult(0)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function EnsureTrailingSlash(ByRef value As String) As String
        If (IsNothing(value)) Then
            value = String.Empty
        End If

        If (Not value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal)) Then
            Return value & "/"
        End If

        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Also, https://login.microsoftonline.com is going to get deprecated soon. Please use b2login.com as detailed in [Set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com for Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have StartupAuth.vb, the whole Startup class code is in the Startup.vb class. Does it matter?

Comment: Also, ida:MetadataAddress was not present in the manual I followed. Is it required? Also I had to comment out <authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>, as otherwise I keep getting this error: 

 Access is denied.   
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Comment: I did add app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate), but it did not help...

Comment: ida:MetadataAddress simplifies configuration. It gets other params from the OIDC metadata endpoint

Comment: Please reuse code in the following ASP.NET using Azure AD B2C sample written in VB.NET. It includes the minimum basics to get an id token: https://github.com/alfredorevilla/azure-ad-b2c-aspnet-vbnet-sample.

Once you get authentication working you can augment your application capabilities.

Let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: So should I use MetadataAddress? You have it commented out in appSettings.config.

Comment: OK, I uncommented it. Also, I realized that the redirect url should be https://localhost:44379/ rather than https://localhost:44379/signin-oidc. It seems to work now.

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing the redirect url finding.